# Upgraded 2.5.5 to 2.6 - Too many redirects when access CP

Tags: upgrade

I just tried to upgrade from 2.5.5 to 2.6.  I followed all of the instructions here:  http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html

Now when I try to access my Control Panel (/system), I'm getting "Too many redirects error": http://foo.local/system/index.php?S=0&D=cpC=homepage

I removed my .htacess rewrite rules and am still getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a [bug in EE2.6](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19334). Here's the proposed fix from that report:

> Changed line 407 of system/expression/libraries/core.php from:
>
> `ee()->functions->redirect(BASE.'C=homepage');`
>
> to:
>
> `ee()->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=homepage');`

Comment: This fixed the issue!  Hopefully they'll get a 2.6.1 out shortly to fix this bug.

Comment: I can confirm that this is *not* fixed in 2.6.1. I never upgraded to 2.6.0 but I just ran into this when going from 2.5.2 to 2.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cookies.

If the problem persists after that, turn off extensions in your config file. Open system/expressionengine/config/config.php and change allow_extensions to n: `$config['allow_extensions'] = "n";`

If you can log in after disabling extensions, then you know the culprit is some extension you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rob's suggestion, it's also worth clearing your caches and if the problem persists then run the upgrade again incase something didn't quite copy over.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same "too many redirects"-error on the ExpressionEngine control panel start page. On all other control panel pages I have no problem ...

Comment: 2.6.1 is out and unfortunately the bug was not fixed!